# Alternative to RemoteView's setTextViewCompoundDrawables

Tags: android

JellyBean (4.1) has brought the super handy method `setTextViewCompoundDrawables` to the `RemoteViews` class, which allows me to change the drawable on a button in a custom Notification on the fly. However, I can't really only support Jelly Bean so I need an old school way to achieve the same effect.

I'm currently doing it by having two different layout files and rebuilding the whole thing, but that is noticeably slow and horrible to maintain. Anyone have a better solution?